# regex validation cyrillic domain

Tags: php, regex, validation

I need to write a regular expression to validate Latin and Cyrillic domain name.
I wrote this function, but it does not work with Cyrillic domains. 
Tell me what's wrong?

```
function isDomain($url)
    {
        if (mb_strlen($url)==0) return false;
        $url = mb_strtolower(trim($url));
        $abc = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщэьъыюя';
        if(!preg_match('/^(['.$abc.'a-z0-9\.-]{1,64})?\.(?:рф|ru|su|com|net|org|mil|edu|arpa|gov|biz|info|aero|inc|name|[a-z]{3})$/i',$url))
        {
            return FALSE; 
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: the problem was the lack mb_internal_encoding ('UTF-8');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use the POSIX class `\p{Cyrillic}`.
2. Use modifier `/u` to match UniCode.
3. Use the Unicode code points for `рф` in your TLD list.

Also an observation: TLD's of length 3 are already matched by `[a-z]{3}`, so we can leave those out of the list.

```
function isDomain($url)
{
    if (mb_strlen($url)==0) return false;
    $url = mb_strtolower(trim($url));
    return preg_match('/^([\p{Cyrillic}\p{Latin}\d\.-]{1,64})?\.(?:\x{0440}\x{0444}|ru|su|arpa|info|aero|name|[a-z]{3})$/iu',$url);
}
```

See my example at [Regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/hK0tS7).

Comment: Do you have an example of a domain you want matched?

Comment: for example абебебу.рф

Comment: See the link to regex101 in my updated answer. Last problem was the domain .рф; we needed to provide those two characters as Unicode code points.

Comment: Well, that's weird. It used to work on Regex101, but following the link today, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:рф|ru|su|com|net|org|mil|edu|arpa|gov|biz|info|aero|inc|name|[a-z]{3})
```

It's not useful to list all these if you add [a-z]{3} at the end ! You could just write :

```
(?:рф|[a-z]{3-4})
```

Comment: I'm interested in another question, why Cyrillic domains not validated ?

Comment: I think you meant to write `[a-z]{3,4}` instead.

Comment: @Amine : Right about the {3-4}, i messed up.
OP : You could try using "\p{L}", which matches a letter character (in any character set).